# Aware of other Apps' start

Tags: android

What I want is: when there is an App start, my App can know it and do something about it.

I had look up the android API but can't resolve it.

Is there any way to make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The general philosophy of Android is that one app should not affect the behaviour of other apps unless it's a system app or a device administrator. And there are no APIs for this for device administrators, so you can't do anything about it. Unless, of course, you modify the platform.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you. In my course project I'm trying to develop a app, user could add some installed app to his black list. Then if user wanna to study or sleep and so on, he could use my app to get into so-called "Concentration Mode", if those app like twitter or facebook started, my app would remind user and let him choose to kill it.

Comment: Your best bet would be to write a custom launcher that has this blacklist and shows a warning if the user presses the Twitter, etc. launch icon.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what do you mean by "do something"

However there is a topActivity field defined in the RunningTaskInfo class. You can get a list of running tasks via the getRunningTasks(int) method in the ActivityManager and can traverse through that list to find the currently active task by checking the topActivity field.